# Computing limit without using L'Hopital, Taylor's series or differentiate terms?

Tags: calculus

I want to solve $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^x-(\operatorname{sen} x)^{\operatorname{sen} x}}{x^3 \ln x}$ without using L'hopital's Rule or Taylor Series. Any help is appreciated.

I want to solve
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^x-(\sin x)^{\sin x}}{x^3 \ln x}
$$

without using L'hopital's Rule or Taylor Series. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  If this problem was assigned, what was the exact wording of the problem?